# Getting the most general form of Mayer-Vietoris from the axioms of homology

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I'd like to derive the most general form of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for homology (in particular: I do not want to use the definition of $H_\ast(X)$ in terms of simplices). By that I mean the existence of an exact sequence of the form
$\cdots \to H_n(X_{12},A_{12})\to H_n(X_1,A_1)\oplus H_n(X_2,A_2)\to H_n(X,A) \to H_{n-1}(X_{12},A_{12})\to\cdots$
whenever $(A,A_1,A_2)\subseteq(X,X_1,X_2)$ are two excisive triads and $A_{12}:=A_1\cap A_2$, $X_{12}:=X_1\cap X_2$.

It is easy to do that in the special case $A=A_1=A_2$ by looking at the two long exact sequences for pairs from the inclusions $A\subseteq X_{12}\subseteq X_1$ and $A\subseteq X_2\subseteq X$ respectively. These two sequences form a Barrett-Whitehead ladder and the lemma of Mayer-Vietoris applies.

Basically the same approach works in the special case $X=X_1=X_2$.

Both of these proofs are well known in the literatur, but so far I was unable to find a proof for the general version either in the books or myself that did not go through the realisation of $H_\ast$ as the homology of some chain-complex generated by simplices.

EDIT: All my previous attempts consisted of doodling one diagram after the other, but may be there is a simpler solution. After realising that $H_\ast(X,A) = \tilde{H}_\ast(C_A^X)$, where $C_A^X$ is the mapping cone of the inclusion $A\to X$, one could also ask whether $(C_A^X, C_{A_1}^{X_1}, C_{A_2}^{X_2})$ is an excisive triad. So I'm asking: Is it?

Comment: In my opinion the biggest problem is *defining* the connecting homomorphsim $H_{n}(X,A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(X_{12},A_{12})$ in the general case. Once this is done, surely a diagram chase will give exactness. Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Not without using simplices. I tried throwing together all kinds of commutative diagrams in the hope that some Barrett-Whitehead-ladder appears which can be utilised, but so far not much success on that front. Do you have any suggestion how it can be done?

Comment: If your homology arises from chain complexes (this works for all simplicial, ordered simplicial and singular homology) then you can construct the connecting morphism with the zig zag lemma (which also gives exactness)

Comment: But if you don't assume that your homology comes from chain complexes, then it really looks like you can't construct that morphism. On the other hand, to try and construct a counter-example, one would need to define an homology without chain complexes (!) and then consider some non triangulable spaces ! Your problem seems quite difficult.

Comment: I'd be very, very surprised if there was a counter-example because of the uniqueness theorem for homology theories satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms.

Comment: Yes that's why one would need to consider non triangulable spaces. Though a counterexample would surprise me very much too. Again, your question is interesting but does seem difficult. Maybe you should post on math overflow ?

Comment: Not just non-triangulable, but not even homotopy equivalent to CW-complexes. It would to be an horrific example of a space and a homology theory. And yet it must satisfy special cases of Mayer-Vietoris. I'm not sure if MO is the right place. I still think that there must be a diagram chasing proof out there and that one just needs to find the right diagram.

Comment: The Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms imply that homotopy pushout diagrams give MV-sequences. At least at the level of $\infty$-categories, there is a `homotopy pushout functor' from spans to squares which preserves hocolims, and hence takes a cofiber sequence of spans (e.g. excisive triads) to a cofiber sequence of squares, so this gives the result. (In other words: I don't know enough point-set topology to know if the triad of mapping cones you have is excisive, but it doesn't matter- the square you write down is still a htpy pushout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was now answered [over on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283003/getting-the-most-general-form-of-mayer-vietoris-from-the-eilenberg-steenrod-axio). The cones are indeed an excisive triad which can be proved by using doubly and triply iterated mapping cones inside commutative squares and cubes.